# Changing timezone in Asp.Net Core container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, nlog, tzdata

I am running my app in a container with the following base image:

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base`

When I publish the app, container timezone is `Greenwich Mean Time` and therefore my NLog entries in the database off by 6 hours.

I can change the timezone by entering into the container and running 
`dpkg-configure tzdata` and after restarting the container, my log entries become normal. However, I am wondering if this can be done through the Dockerfile or the run flags ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to set `ENV` in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin
```